# Intellisense help for JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio

Is there a way to create an intellisense template for JSON in javascript? It would be cool to have some IDE help when working on the client/javascript portion of my application.

Comment: Are you talking about actual JSON, or about the JavaScript "object literal" syntax from which JSON was distilled?  If you're talking about real JSON, I can't imagine how something like Intellisense could act predictively for property names or values, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: The Aptana IDE will give you some code assist with Javascript/JQuery.

Comment: Aptana looks pretty cool. I'll take a look, thanks!

Comment: I started using this syntax: `var fakeyJSONIntellisense = json || { name: null, value: null };` It's a hack obviously, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this a workable solution:

```
var json = null; // Replace with actual JSON when ready.
var fakeyJSONIntellisense = json || { key: null, value: null };
```

This gives the intellisense something to work with. Simply replace the `json` variable with the actual JSON in production, and you're all set.